Looking for fast large-scale image embeddings comparison database structure
I plan to store 1-2 million of entities into a database. Each entity will be linked to 10-100 image embeddings. The goal is to use an external image that may or may not be part of the database and compare it to every stored embedding to find the most simmilar entity it could belong to.
I wish to ask, what kind of a database is most suitable for this task and why? How much slower would PostgreSQL with pgvector be compared to a more specialized DB such as Milvus or FAISS?

What is an "image embedding"?...the Exif data?

@J.D. A vector representation of the image, with the intention of recognizing simmilar images. I would use better tags, but this sub has none that are available on stackoverflow, ironically stackoverflow does not allow questions such as this one.

Since most people on here probably don't have experience working with vector representations of an image, it might be helpful to include a data example and / or go into further details of what that looks like. I would assume you mean the image is converted into some textual form. If so, it would be good to see a sample of what that looks like or have a better description on the properties of that data such as typical length etc. "stackoverflow does not allow questions such as this one" - Correct, StackOverflow isn't meant for database questions, because of the specificity of the topic.
